# Gunicorn and django 1.7: unable to find module wgsi

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I'm using Django 1.7 with Python 3.4. I wanted to deploy a django project, but I was unable to do it, so I tried with a new created project, without any exit.

For this, I've created a virtualenv and activated it. After this, I've created an empty django project through `django-admin.py startproject name`, `cd name` and `python manage.py migrate`. I was able to run server with `python manage.py runserver`.

After this, on same folder, I tried to launch it with gunicorn (`gunicorn name.wgsi:application`), without any success. It says `No module named name.wgsi`

```
(venv)ubuntu@ubuntu:~/name$ gunicorn name.wgsi:application
Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/test/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/var/www/test/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 114, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/var/www/test/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 66, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/var/www/test/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/var/www/test/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/var/www/test/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 356, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named 'name.wgsi'
```

I also post my working tree:

```
(venv)ubuntu@ubuntu:~/name$ tree
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
└── name
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── settings.cpython-34.pyc
    │   └── wsgi.cpython-34.pyc
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py

2 directories, 9 files
```

Comment: What about to use a `--reload` and `--chdir` to fix the working directory?

Comment: Try `gunicorn --chdir ~/name/ name.wsgi:application`

Comment: I've tried and the error keeps being the same

Comment: can you show the content of  `wsgi.py`? Did you alter that?

Comment: I've changed nothing form default django project. wsgi looks like this: http://pastebin.com/CDGVzkD5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `gunicorn name.wsgi:application`

There is a small typo. `wgsi` should be `wsgi`